# Delphi: Punicode Decode

Tags: delphi, decode, punycode

Found the information as encoded in Punycode: [Cyrillic domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285436/cyrillic-domain-name) , but but how do I decode back (punycode in cyrillic)?

Comment: follow the link in the answer to which you linked!!

Comment: and? Henri Gourvest has written a function which with of that unit encodes in pynicode. Need function, which DECODE pynicode with that unit!

Comment: I see encode and decode in that unit

Comment: you know the parameters for those functions? :) for encode - this func: function PEncode(const str: UnicodeString): AnsiString;
var
  len: Cardinal;
begin
  Result := '';
  if (PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len) = pcSuccess) and (Length(str) + 1 <> len) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, len);
    PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len, PByte(Result));
    Result := 'xn--' + Result;
  end else
    Result := AnsiString(str);
end;

Comment: You should expand your question rather than commenting. It seems to me that your question is "how do I call the decode function?"

Answer (score 2):

The code to which you link does not work. The `PunycodeDecode` function is broken. Line 416 reads:

```
move(output[i], output[i + 1], (outidx - i) * SizeOf(output^));
```

This is a mis-translation from C. Instead it should read:

```
move(output[i], output[i + 1], (outidx - i) * SizeOf(output^[0]));
```

After making this change, I successfully tested the following program:

```
program Punycode;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils,
  dorPunyCode in 'dorPunyCode.pas';

function PEncode(const str: UnicodeString): AnsiString;
var
  len: Cardinal;
begin
  if str = '' then
  begin
    Result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  if (PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len) = pcSuccess) and (Length(str) + 1 <> len) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, len);
    PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len, PByte(Result));
  end else
    Result := str;
end;

function PDecode(const str: AnsiString): UnicodeString;
var
  outputlen: Cardinal;
begin
  if str = '' then
  begin
    Result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  outputlen := 0;
  if (PunycodeDecode(Length(str), PByte(str), outputlen) = pcSuccess) and (Length(str) + 1 <> outputlen) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, outputlen);
    PunycodeDecode(Length(str), PByte(str), outputlen, PPunycode(Result));
  end else
    Result := str;
end;

procedure Test(const Input: UnicodeString);
begin
  if PDecode(PEncode(Input))<>Input then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Round-trip failed: %s', [Input]);
end;

begin
  Test('http://президент.рф/');
  Test('David Heffernan');
  Test('');
  Test('A');
end.
```

However, I know exactly nothing about Punycode and in particular I've no idea what the point of the `'xn--'` prefix that is added at the question to which you linked. So the `PEncode` and `PDecode` routines that I show above are probably not exactly what you need.

I am extremely dubious of the Delphi code in the `dorPunyCode` unit and I suspect that there are other problems lurking. In your position I would get hold of `punycode.c`, compile it with `bcc32` and then link to it with `$L`. I would regard that as much more trustworthy than this `dorPunyCode` unit.

Comment: You can say more about where  i can get punycode.c and how to link "to it with $L"? This is my first time with this encounter.

Comment: There's a link at the top of the Delphi unit. Do you know much about punycode?

Comment: [The GNI IDN library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/) has instructions and examples.  [This](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libidn.git/tree/examples/example.c) shows you how to compile libIDN and [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/libidn.git/tree/examples/example2.c) is an example of how to use punycode.

Comment: Thank you David I commited your fix. I don't know why you consider my code as "extremely dubious", it is a C to Delphi conversion, bugs can happen, it is ok as long they are reported and fixed.

Comment: xn-- is not part of puny code specifications, it is only used as a prefix to detect puny encoding in domain urls.

Comment: @henri sure bugs happen. I make lots of mistakes just as we all do. But I could not vouch for this code since it clearly had no testing at all. Any testing would have found that bug so who knows what else could be wrong. I did not want to give it a seal of approval. I hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

There are some more bugs in this code.

Here is test for it:

```
program PunyCodeTest;

uses
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  SysUtils,
  PunyCode in '..\SRC\PunyCode.pas';

type
  TCodecTestRec = record
    Decoded: AnsiString;
    Encoded: AnsiString;
  end;

  TDomainTestRec = record
    Decoded: WideString;
    Encoded: AnsiString;
  end;

const
  CodecTestCases: array [0..19] of TCodecTestRec = (
    // My samples
    // ----------
    // 蒙古火锅-test
    (Decoded: 'u+8499 u+53E4 u+706B u+9505 u+002D u+0074 u+0065 u+0073 u+0074';
     Encoded: '-test-xt8h571o0z7ad54a'),

    // RFC 3492 - 7.1 Sample strings
    // -----------------------------
    // (A) Arabic (Egyptian):
    (Decoded: 'u+0644 u+064A u+0647 u+0645 u+0627 u+0628 u+062A u+0643 u+0644 '+
       'u+0645 u+0648 u+0634 u+0639 u+0631 u+0628 u+064A u+061F';
     Encoded: 'egbpdaj6bu4bxfgehfvwxn'),

    //(B) Chinese (simplified):
    (Decoded: 'u+4ED6 u+4EEC u+4E3A u+4EC0 u+4E48 u+4E0D u+8BF4 u+4E2D u+6587';
     Encoded: 'ihqwcrb4cv8a8dqg056pqjye'),

    // (C) Chinese (traditional):
    (Decoded: 'u+4ED6 u+5011 u+7232 u+4EC0 u+9EBD u+4E0D u+8AAA u+4E2D u+6587';
     Encoded: 'ihqwctvzc91f659drss3x8bo0yb'),

    // (D) Czech: Pro<ccaron>prost<ecaron>nemluv<iacute><ccaron>esky
    (Decoded: 'U+0050 u+0072 u+006F u+010D u+0070 u+0072 u+006F u+0073 u+0074 '+
       'u+011B u+006E u+0065 u+006D u+006C u+0075 u+0076 u+00ED u+010D u+0065 '+
       'u+0073 u+006B u+0079';
     Encoded: 'Proprostnemluvesky-uyb24dma41a'),

    // (E) Hebrew:
    (Decoded: 'u+05DC u+05DE u+05D4 u+05D4 u+05DD u+05E4 u+05E9 u+05D5 u+05D8 '+
       'u+05DC u+05D0 u+05DE u+05D3 u+05D1 u+05E8 u+05D9 u+05DD u+05E2 u+05D1 '+
       'u+05E8 u+05D9 u+05EA';
     Encoded: '4dbcagdahymbxekheh6e0a7fei0b'),

    // (F) Hindi (Devanagari):
    (Decoded: 'u+092F u+0939 u+0932 u+094B u+0917 u+0939 u+093F u+0928 u+094D '+
       'u+0926 u+0940 u+0915 u+094D u+092F u+094B u+0902 u+0928 u+0939 u+0940 '+
       'u+0902 u+092C u+094B u+0932 u+0938 u+0915 u+0924 u+0947 u+0939 u+0948 '+
       'u+0902';
     Encoded: 'i1baa7eci9glrd9b2ae1bj0hfcgg6iyaf8o0a1dig0cd'),

    // (G) Japanese (kanji and hiragana):
    (Decoded: 'u+306A u+305C u+307F u+3093 u+306A u+65E5 u+672C u+8A9E u+3092 '+
       'u+8A71 u+3057 u+3066 u+304F u+308C u+306A u+3044 u+306E u+304B';
     Encoded: 'n8jok5ay5dzabd5bym9f0cm5685rrjetr6pdxa'),

    // (H) Korean (Hangul syllables):
    (Decoded: 'u+C138 u+ACC4 u+C758 u+BAA8 u+B4E0 u+C0AC u+B78C u+B4E4 u+C774 '+
       'u+D55C u+AD6D u+C5B4 u+B97C u+C774 u+D574 u+D55C u+B2E4 u+BA74 u+C5BC '+
       'u+B9C8 u+B098 u+C88B u+C744 u+AE4C';
     Encoded: '989aomsvi5e83db1d2a355cv1e0vak1dwrv93d5xbh15a0dt30a5jpsd879ccm6fea98c'),

    // (I) Russian (Cyrillic):
    (Decoded: 'U+043F u+043E u+0447 u+0435 u+043C u+0443 u+0436 u+0435 u+043E '+
       'u+043D u+0438 u+043D u+0435 u+0433 u+043E u+0432 u+043E u+0440 u+044F '+
       'u+0442 u+043F u+043E u+0440 u+0443 u+0441 u+0441 u+043A u+0438';
     Encoded: 'b1abfaaepdrnnbgefbaDotcwatmq2g4l'),

    // (J) Spanish: Porqu<eacute>nopuedensimplementehablarenEspa<ntilde>ol
    (Decoded: 'U+0050 u+006F u+0072 u+0071 u+0075 u+00E9 u+006E u+006F u+0070 '+
       'u+0075 u+0065 u+0064 u+0065 u+006E u+0073 u+0069 u+006D u+0070 u+006C '+
       'u+0065 u+006D u+0065 u+006E u+0074 u+0065 u+0068 u+0061 u+0062 u+006C '+
       'u+0061 u+0072 u+0065 u+006E U+0045 u+0073 u+0070 u+0061 u+00F1 u+006F '+
       'u+006C';
     Encoded: 'PorqunopuedensimplementehablarenEspaol-fmd56a'),

    // (K) Vietnamese:
    // T<adotbelow>isaoh<odotbelow>kh<ocirc>ngth<ecirchookabove>ch\
    // <ihookabove>n<oacute>iti<ecircacute>ngVi<ecircdotbelow>t
    (Decoded: 'U+0054 u+1EA1 u+0069 u+0073 u+0061 u+006F u+0068 u+1ECD u+006B '+
       'u+0068 u+00F4 u+006E u+0067 u+0074 u+0068 u+1EC3 u+0063 u+0068 u+1EC9 '+
       'u+006E u+00F3 u+0069 u+0074 u+0069 u+1EBF u+006E u+0067 U+0056 u+0069 '+
       'u+1EC7 u+0074';
     Encoded: 'TisaohkhngthchnitingVit-kjcr8268qyxafd2f1b9g'),

    // (L) 3<nen>B<gumi><kinpachi><sensei>
    (Decoded: 'u+0033 u+5E74 U+0042 u+7D44 u+91D1 u+516B u+5148 u+751F';
     Encoded: '3B-ww4c5e180e575a65lsy2b'),

    // (M) <amuro><namie>-with-SUPER-MONKEYS
    (Decoded: 'u+5B89 u+5BA4 u+5948 u+7F8E u+6075 u+002D u+0077 u+0069 u+0074 '+
       'u+0068 u+002D U+0053 U+0055 U+0050 U+0045 U+0052 u+002D U+004D U+004F '+
       'U+004E U+004B U+0045 U+0059 U+0053';
     Encoded: '-with-SUPER-MONKEYS-pc58ag80a8qai00g7n9n'),

    // (N) Hello-Another-Way-<sorezore><no><basho>
    (Decoded: 'U+0048 u+0065 u+006C u+006C u+006F u+002D U+0041 u+006E u+006F '+
       'u+0074 u+0068 u+0065 u+0072 u+002D U+0057 u+0061 u+0079 u+002D u+305D '+
       'u+308C u+305E u+308C u+306E u+5834 u+6240';
     Encoded: 'Hello-Another-Way--fc4qua05auwb3674vfr0b'),

    // (O) <hitotsu><yane><no><shita>2
    (Decoded: 'u+3072 u+3068 u+3064 u+5C4B u+6839 u+306E u+4E0B u+0032';
     Encoded: '2-u9tlzr9756bt3uc0v'),

    // (P) Maji<de>Koi<suru>5<byou><mae>
    (Decoded: 'U+004D u+0061 u+006A u+0069 u+3067 U+004B u+006F u+0069 u+3059 '+
       'u+308B u+0035 u+79D2 u+524D';
     Encoded: 'MajiKoi5-783gue6qz075azm5e'),

    // (Q) <pafii>de<runba>
    (Decoded: 'u+30D1 u+30D5 u+30A3 u+30FC u+0064 u+0065 u+30EB u+30F3 u+30D0';
     Encoded: 'de-jg4avhby1noc0d'),

    // (R) <sono><supiido><de>
    (Decoded: 'u+305D u+306E u+30B9 u+30D4 u+30FC u+30C9 u+3067';
     Encoded: 'd9juau41awczczp'),

    // (S) -> $1.00 <-
    (Decoded: 'u+002D u+003E u+0020 u+0024 u+0031 u+002E u+0030 u+0030 u+0020 '+
       'u+003C u+002D';
     Encoded: '-> $1.00 <--')
  );

  DomainTestCases: array [0..2] of TDomainTestRec = (
    (Decoded: '蒙古火锅-test.cn'; Encoded: 'xn---test-xt8h571o0z7ad54a.cn'),
    (Decoded: 'президент.рф'; Encoded: 'xn--d1abbgf6aiiy.xn--p1ai'),
    (Decoded: 'почта.мд'; Encoded: 'xn--80a1acny.xn--d1ap')
  );

const
  UnicodeMaxLength = 256;
  AceMaxLength = 256;

function ExtractCodePoint(S: AnsiString; var Off: Integer; out caseflag: Byte; out codept: TPunyCode): Boolean;

  procedure InvalidInput;
  begin
    raise EAssertionFailed.Create('Invalid input');
  end;

begin
  Result := False;
  if Off > Length(S) then Exit;
  if Off+5 > Length(S) then InvalidInput;

  if S[Off] = 'u' then caseflag := 0
  else if S[Off] = 'U' then caseflag := 1
  else InvalidInput;
  Inc(Off);

  if S[Off] <> '+' then InvalidInput;
  Inc(Off);

  codept := StrToInt('$'+Copy(S, Off, 4));
  Inc(Off, 4);

  if (Off <= Length(S)) and (S[Off] <> ' ') then InvalidInput;
  Inc(Off);

  Result := True;
end;

procedure TestEncoder(Decoded, Encoded: AnsiString);
var
  inlen, outlen: Cardinal;
  caseflags: array [0..UnicodeMaxLength-1] of Byte;
  input: array [0..UnicodeMaxLength-1] of TPunyCode;
  output: array [0..AceMaxLength-1] of Byte;
  Off: Integer;
  caseflag: Byte;
  codept: TPunyCode;
begin
  inlen := 0;
  Off := 1;
  while ExtractCodePoint(Decoded, Off, caseflag, codept) do
  begin
    caseflags[inlen] := caseflag;
    input[inlen] := codept;
    Inc(inlen);
  end;

  outlen := AceMaxLength;
  if (PunycodeEncode(inlen, @input, outlen, @output, @caseflags) <> pcSuccess) or
    (outlen <> Cardinal(Length(Encoded))) or
    not CompareMem(@output, @Encoded[1], outlen) then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Encoding failed: %s', [Decoded]);
end;

function MakeDecoded(outlen: Cardinal; output: PPunycode; caseflags: PByte): AnsiString;
var
  _caseflags: PByteArray absolute caseflags;
  I: Integer;
  S: AnsiString;
begin
  Result := '';
  for I := 0 to outlen - 1 do
  begin
    if _caseflags[I] = 0 then S := 'u+'
    else S := 'U+';
    S := S + IntToHex(output[I], 4);
    if Result = '' then Result := S
    else Result := Result + ' ' + S;
  end;
end;

procedure TestDecoder(Decoded, Encoded: AnsiString);
var
  inlen, outlen: Cardinal;
  caseflags: array [0..UnicodeMaxLength-1] of Byte;
  output: array [0..UnicodeMaxLength-1] of TPunyCode;
begin
  inlen := Length(Encoded);
  if inlen > AceMaxLength then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Input is too big: %s', [Encoded]);

  outlen := UnicodeMaxLength;
  if (PunycodeDecode(inlen, PByte(@Encoded[1]), outlen, @output, @caseflags) <> pcSuccess) or
    (MakeDecoded(outlen, @output, @caseflags) <> Decoded) then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Decoding failed: %s', [Encoded]);
end;

procedure TestCodec(Decoded, Encoded: AnsiString);
begin
  TestEncoder(Decoded, Encoded);
  TestDecoder(Decoded, Encoded);
end;

procedure TestCodecTestCases;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(CodecTestCases) do
    TestCodec(CodecTestCases[I].Decoded, CodecTestCases[I].Encoded);
end;

procedure TestDomain(Decoded: WideString; Encoded: AnsiString);
begin
  if PunycodeEncodeDomain(Decoded) <> Encoded then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Encoding failed: %s', [Decoded]);
  if PunycodeDecodeDomain(Encoded) <> Decoded then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Decoding failed: %s', [Encoded]);
end;

procedure TestDomainTestCases;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to High(DomainTestCases) do
    TestDomain(DomainTestCases[I].Decoded, DomainTestCases[I].Encoded);
end;

begin
  TestCodecTestCases;
  TestDomainTestCases;
  MessageDlg('Punycode was successfully tested', mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
end.
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is fixed version with PunycodeDecodeDomain added. Tested in Dephi 2007 and Delphi XE3 (x86 and x64):

```
(*
 * punycode.c from RFC 3492prop
 * http://www.nicemice.net/idn/
 * Adam M. Costello
 * http://www.nicemice.net/amc/
 *
 * This is ANSI C code (C89) implementing Punycode (RFC 3492prop).
 * Delphi Conversion by:
 *   Henri Gourvest <hgourvest@gmail.com>
 *   http://www.progdigy.com
 * contributor
 *   J. Heffernan <info@heffs.org.uk>
 * testing, fixing and refactoring
 *   Igor Tsurcanovsky <Igor@ritlabs.com>

usage:

function PEncode(const str: UnicodeString): AnsiString;
var
  len: Cardinal;
begin
  if str = '' then
  begin
    Result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  if (PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len) = pcSuccess) and (Length(str) + 1 <> len) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, len);
    PunycodeEncode(Length(str), PPunyCode(str), len, PByte(Result));
  end else
    Result := str;
end;

function PDecode(const str: AnsiString): UnicodeString;
var
  outputlen: Cardinal;
begin
  if str = '' then
  begin
    Result := '';
    exit;
  end;
  outputlen := 0;
  if (PunycodeDecode(Length(str), PByte(str), outputlen) = pcSuccess) and (Length(str) <> outputlen) then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, outputlen);
    PunycodeDecode(Length(str), PByte(str), outputlen, PPunycode(Result));
  end else
    Result := str;
end;

procedure Test(const Input: UnicodeString);
begin
  if PDecode(PEncode(Input))<>Input then
    raise EAssertionFailed.CreateFmt('Round-trip failed: %s', [Input]);
end;

begin
  Test('президент');
  Test('David Heffernan');
  Test('');
  Test('A');
end.

 *)

unit PunyCode;

interface

type
  {$if (SizeOf(Char) = 1)}
  // For compatibility with versions without UnicodeString (prior Delphi 2009)
  UnicodeString = WideString;
  {$ifend}

  TPunyCodeStatus = (
    pcSuccess,
    pcBadInput,   (* Input is invalid.                       *)
    pcBigOutput,  (* Output would exceed the space provided. *)
    pcOverflow    (* Input needs wider integers to process.  *)
  );

  TPunyCode = Word;
  TPunyCodeArray = array[0..(High(Integer) div SizeOf(TPunyCode)) - 1] of TPunyCode;
  PPunycode = ^TPunyCodeArray;

function PunycodeDecode(inputlen: Cardinal; const input: PByte;
  var outputlen: Cardinal; output: PPunycode = nil;
  caseflags: PByte = nil): TPunyCodeStatus;

function PunycodeEncode(inputlen: Cardinal; const input: PPunycode;
  var outputlen: Cardinal; const output: PByte = nil;
  const caseflags: PByte = nil): TPunyCodeStatus; overload;

function PunycodeDecodeDomain(const str: AnsiString): UnicodeString;
function PunycodeEncodeDomain(const str: UnicodeString): AnsiString;

implementation

uses SysUtils;

type
  PByteArray = ^TByteArray;
  TByteArray = array [0..MaxInt-1] of Byte;

(*** Bootstring parameters for Punycode ***)
const
  PUNY_BASE = 36;
  PUNY_TMIN = 1;
  PUNY_TMAX = 26;
  PUNY_SKEW = 38;
  PUNY_DAMP = 700;
  PUNY_INITIAL_BIAS = 72;
  PUNY_INITIAL_N = $80;
  PUNY_DELIMITER = $2D;

  // typedef unsigned int punycode_uint;
  // /* maxint is the maximum value of a punycode_uint variable: */
  // static const punycode_uint maxint = -1;
  // /* Because maxint is unsigned, -1 becomes the maximum value. */
  PUNY_maxint = High(Cardinal);


(* flagged(bcp) tests whether a basic code point is flagged *)
(* (uppercase).  The behavior is undefined if bcp is not a  *)
(* basic code point.                                        *)

function PUNY_flagged(bcp: Cardinal): Byte; inline;
begin
  Result := Ord(bcp - 65 < 26);
end;

(* DecodeDigit(cp) returns the numeric value of a basic code *)
(* point (for use in representing integers) in the range 0 to *)
(* BASE-1, or BASE if cp is does not represent a value.       *)

function PUNY_DecodeDigit(cp: Cardinal): Cardinal; inline;
begin
  if (cp - 48 < 10) then
    Result := cp - 22
  else if (cp - 65 < 26) then
    Result := cp - 65
  else if (cp - 97 < 26) then
    Result := cp - 97
  else
    Result := PUNY_BASE;
end;

(* EncodeDigit(d,flag) returns the basic code point whose value      *)
(* (when used for representing integers) is d, which needs to be in   *)
(* the range 0 to BASE-1.  The lowercase form is used unless flag is  *)
(* nonzero, in which case the uppercase form is used.  The behavior   *)
(* is undefined if flag is nonzero and digit d has no uppercase form. *)

function PUNY_EncodeDigit(d: Cardinal; flag: Boolean): Byte; inline;
begin
  Result := d + 22 + 75 * Ord(d < 26) - (Ord(flag) shl 5);
  (*  0..25 map to ASCII a..z or A..Z *)
  (* 26..35 map to ASCII 0..9         *)
end;

(* EncodeBasic(bcp,flag) forces a basic code point to lowercase *)
(* if flag is zero, uppercase if flag is nonzero, and returns    *)
(* the resulting code point.  The code point is unchanged if it  *)
(* is caseless.  The behavior is undefined if bcp is not a basic *)
(* code point.                                                   *)

function PUNY_EncodeBasic(bcp: Cardinal; flag: Integer): Byte; inline;
begin
  Dec(bcp, Ord(bcp - 97 < 26) shl 5);
  Result := bcp + (((not flag) and Ord(bcp - 65 < 26)) shl 5);
end;

(*** Bias adaptation function ***)

function PUNY_Adapt(delta, numpoints: Cardinal; firsttime: Boolean): Cardinal; inline;
var
  k: TPunyCode;
begin
  if firsttime then
    delta := delta div PUNY_DAMP
  else
    delta := delta shr 1;

  (* delta shr 1 is a faster way of doing delta div 2 *)
  Inc(delta, delta div numpoints);

  k := 0;
  while (delta > ((PUNY_BASE - PUNY_TMIN) * PUNY_TMAX) div 2) do
  begin
    delta := delta div (PUNY_BASE - PUNY_TMIN);
    Inc(k, PUNY_BASE);
  end;

  Result := k + (PUNY_BASE - PUNY_TMIN + 1) * delta div (delta + PUNY_SKEW);
end;

(* PunycodeEncode() converts Unicode to Punycode.  The input     *)
(* is represented as an array of Unicode code points (not code    *)
(* units; surrogate pairs are not allowed), and the output        *)
(* will be represented as an array of ASCII code points.  The     *)
(* output string is *not* null-terminated; it will contain        *)
(* zeros if and only if the input contains zeros.  (Of course     *)
(* the caller can leave room for a terminator and add one if      *)
(* needed.)  The inputlen is the number of code points in         *)
(* the input.  The outputlen is an in/out argument: the           *)
(* caller passes in the maximum number of code points that it     *)
(* can receive, and on successful return it will contain the      *)
(* number of code points actually output.  The case_flags array   *)
(* holds input_length boolean values, where nonzero suggests that *)
(* the corresponding Unicode character be forced to uppercase     *)
(* after being decoded (if possible), and zero suggests that      *)
(* it be forced to lowercase (if possible).  ASCII code points    *)
(* are encoded literally, except that ASCII letters are forced    *)
(* to uppercase or lowercase according to the corresponding       *)
(* uppercase flags.  If case_flags is a null pointer then ASCII   *)
(* letters are left as they are, and other code points are        *)
(* treated as if their uppercase flags were zero.  The return     *)
(* value can be any of the TPunyCodeStatus values defined above   *)
(* except pcBadInput; if not pcSuccess, then       *)
(* output_size and output might contain garbage.                  *)

function PunycodeEncode(inputlen: Cardinal; const input: PPunycode;
  var outputlen: Cardinal; const output: PByte = nil;
  const caseflags: PByte = nil): TPunyCodeStatus;
var
  outidx, maxout, n, delta, h, b, bias, m, q, k, t: Cardinal;
  j: Integer;
  _output: PByteArray absolute output;
  _caseflags: PByteArray absolute caseflags;
begin
  (* Initialize the state: *)

  n := PUNY_INITIAL_N;
  outidx := 0;
  delta := outidx;
  maxout := outputlen;
  bias := PUNY_INITIAL_BIAS;

  (* Handle the basic code points: *)

  for j := 0 to inputlen - 1 do
  begin
    if (input[j] < $80) then
    begin
      if (output <> nil) then
      begin
        if (maxout - outidx < 2) then
        begin
          Result := pcBigOutput;
          Exit;
        end;
        if (caseflags <> nil) then
          _output[outidx] := PUNY_EncodeBasic(input[j], _caseflags[j])
        else
          _output[outidx] := input[j];
      end;

      Inc(outidx);
    end;
    (* else if (input[j] < n) return pcBadInput; *)
    (* (not needed for Punycode with unsigned code points) *)
  end;

  b := outidx;
  h := b;

  (* h is the number of code points that have been handled, b is the *)
  (* number of basic code points, and out is the number of characters *)
  (* that have been output. *)

  if (b > 0) then
  begin
    if (output <> nil) then
      _output[outidx] := PUNY_DELIMITER;
    Inc(outidx);
  end;

  (* Main encoding loop: *)

  while (h < inputlen) do
  begin
    (* All non-basic code points < n have been *)
    (* handled already.  Find the next larger one: *)

    m := PUNY_maxint;
    for j := 0 to inputlen - 1 do
      (* if (basic(input[j])) continue; *)
      (* (not needed for Punycode) *)
      if ((input[j] >= n) and (input[j] < m)) then
        m := input[j];

    (* Increase delta enough to advance the decoder's *)
    (* <n,i> state to <m,0>, but guard against overflow: *)

    if (m - n > (PUNY_maxint - delta) div (h + 1)) then
    begin
      Result := pcOverflow;
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(delta, (m - n) * (h + 1));
    n := m;

    for j := 0 to inputlen - 1 do
    begin
      (* Punycode does not need to check whether input[j] is basic: *)
      if (input[j] < n (* or basic(input[j]) *) ) then
      begin
        Inc(delta);
        if (delta = 0) then
        begin
          Result := pcOverflow;
          Exit;
        end;
      end;

      if (input[j] = n) then
      begin
        (* Represent delta as a generalized variable-length integer: *)

        q := delta;
        k := PUNY_BASE;
        while true do
        begin
          if (output <> nil) then
            if (outidx >= maxout) then
            begin
              Result := pcBigOutput;
              Exit;
            end;
          if k <= bias (* + TMIN *) then (* +TMIN not needed *)
            t := PUNY_TMIN
          else if k >= bias + PUNY_TMAX then
            t := PUNY_TMAX
          else
            t := k - bias;
          if (q < t) then
            break;
          if (output <> nil) then
            _output[outidx] := PUNY_EncodeDigit(t + (q - t) mod (PUNY_BASE - t), False);
          Inc(outidx);
          q := (q - t) div (PUNY_BASE - t);
          Inc(k, PUNY_BASE);
        end;
        if (output <> nil) then
          _output[outidx] := PUNY_EncodeDigit(q,
            (caseflags <> nil) and (_caseflags[j] <> 0));
        Inc(outidx);
        bias := PUNY_Adapt(delta, h + 1, h = b);
        delta := 0;
        Inc(h);
      end;
    end;

    Inc(delta);
    Inc(n);
  end;

  outputlen := outidx;
  Result := pcSuccess;
end;

(* PunycodeDecode() converts Punycode to Unicode.  The input is  *)
(* represented as an array of ASCII code points, and the output   *)
(* will be represented as an array of Unicode code points.  The   *)
(* input_length is the number of code points in the input.  The   *)
(* output_length is an in/out argument: the caller passes in      *)
(* the maximum number of code points that it can receive, and     *)
(* on successful return it will contain the actual number of      *)
(* code points output.  The case_flags array needs room for at    *)
(* least output_length values, or it can be a null pointer if the *)
(* case information is not needed.  A nonzero flag suggests that  *)
(* the corresponding Unicode character be forced to uppercase     *)
(* by the caller (if possible), while zero suggests that it be    *)
(* forced to lowercase (if possible).  ASCII code points are      *)
(* output already in the proper case, but their flags will be set *)
(* appropriately so that applying the flags would be harmless.    *)
(* The return value can be any of the TPunyCodeStatus values      *)
(* defined above; if not pcSuccess, then output_length,    *)
(* output, and case_flags might contain garbage.  On success, the *)
(* decoder will never need to write an output_length greater than *)
(* input_length, because of how the encoding is defined.          *)

function PunycodeDecode(inputlen: Cardinal; const input: PByte;
  var outputlen: Cardinal; output: PPunycode;
  caseflags: PByte): TPunyCodeStatus;
var
  outidx, i, maxout, bias, b, inidx, oldi, w, k, digit, t, n : Cardinal;
  j: Integer;
  _input: PByteArray absolute input;
  _caseflags: PByteArray absolute caseflags;
begin

  (* Initialize the state: *)

  n := PUNY_INITIAL_N;
  outidx := 0;
  i := outidx;
  maxout := outputlen;
  bias := PUNY_INITIAL_BIAS;

  (* Handle the basic code points:  Let b be the number of input code *)
  (* points before the last DELIMITER, or 0 if there is none, then *)
  (* copy the first b code points to the output. *)

  b := 0;
  for j := 0 to inputlen - 1 do
    if _input[j] = PUNY_DELIMITER then
      b := j;

  if output <> nil then
    if (b > maxout) then
    begin
      Result := pcBigOutput;
      Exit;
    end;

  for j := 0 to b - 1 do
  begin
    if (caseflags <> nil) then
      _caseflags[outidx] := PUNY_flagged(_input[j]);
    if (_input[j] >= $80) then
    begin
      Result := pcBadInput;
      Exit;
    end;
    if output <> nil then
      output[outidx] := _input[j];
    Inc(outidx);
  end;

  (* Main decoding loop:  Start just after the last DELIMITER if any *)
  (* basic code points were copied; start at the beginning otherwise. *)

  if (b > 0) then
    inidx := b + 1
  else
    inidx := 0;

  while inidx < inputlen do
  begin
    (* in is the index of the next character to be consumed, and *)
    (* out is the number of code points in the output array. *)

    (* Decode a generalized variable-length integer into delta, *)
    (* which gets added to i.  The overflow checking is easier *)
    (* if we increase i as we go, then subtract off its starting *)
    (* value at the end to obtain delta. *)

    oldi := i;
    w := 1;
    k := PUNY_BASE;
    while true do
    begin
      if (inidx >= inputlen) then
      begin
        Result := pcBadInput;
        Exit;
      end;
      digit := PUNY_DecodeDigit(_input[inidx]);
      Inc(inidx);
      if (digit >= PUNY_BASE) then
      begin
        Result := pcBadInput;
        Exit;
      end;
      if (digit > (PUNY_maxint - i) div w) then
      begin
        Result := pcOverflow;
        Exit;
      end;
      Inc(i, digit * w);
      if k <= bias (* + TMIN *) then
        t := PUNY_TMIN
      else (* +TMIN not needed *)
      if k >= bias + PUNY_TMAX then
        t := PUNY_TMAX
      else
        t := k - bias;
      if (digit < t) then
        break;
      if (w > (PUNY_maxint div (PUNY_BASE - t))) then
      begin
        Result := pcOverflow;
        Exit;
      end;
      w := w * (PUNY_BASE - t);
      Inc(k, PUNY_BASE);
    end;

    bias := PUNY_Adapt(i - oldi, outidx + 1, oldi = 0);

    (* i was supposed to wrap around from out+1 to 0, *)
    (* incrementing n each time, so we'll fix that now: *)

    if (i div (outidx + 1) > PUNY_maxint - n) then
    begin
      Result := pcOverflow;
      Exit;
    end;
    Inc(n, i div (outidx + 1));
    i := i mod (outidx + 1);

    (* Insert n at position i of the output: *)

    (* not needed for Punycode: *)
    (* if (DecodeDigit(n) <= BASE) return punycode_invalid_input; *)
    if output <> nil then
      if (outidx >= maxout) then
      begin
        Result := pcBigOutput;
        Exit;
      end;

    if (caseflags <> nil) then
    begin
      move(_caseflags[i], _caseflags[i + 1], outidx - i);

      (* Case of last character determines uppercase flag: *)
      _caseflags[i] := PUNY_flagged(_input[inidx - 1]);
    end;

    if output <> nil then
    begin
      move(output[i], output[i + 1], (outidx - i) * SizeOf(TPunyCode));
      output[i] := n;
    end;
    Inc(i);

    Inc(outidx);
  end;

  outputlen := outidx;
  Result := pcSuccess;
end;

function PunycodeDecodeDomain(const str: AnsiString): UnicodeString;
var
  p, s: PAnsiChar;

  procedure DoIt(dot: Boolean);
  var
    inlen, outlen: Cardinal;
    unicode: UnicodeString;
    u: PWideChar;
  begin
    inlen := p - s;
    if (inlen > 4) and (StrLIComp(s, 'xn--', 4) = 0) and
      (PunycodeDecode(inlen-4, PByte(@s[4]), outlen) = pcSuccess) then
    begin
      if dot then
        SetLength(unicode, outlen + 1)
      else
        SetLength(unicode, outlen);
      u := PWideChar(unicode);
      PunycodeDecode(inlen-4, PByte(@s[4]), outlen, PPunyCode(u));
      if dot then
      begin
        inc(u, outlen);
        u^ := '.';
      end;
    end else
      if dot then
        SetString(unicode, s, inlen + 1)
      else
        SetString(unicode, s, inlen);
    Result := Result + unicode;
  end;

begin
  Result := '';
  p := PAnsiChar(str);
  s := p;

  while True do
  case p^ of
    '.':
      begin
        DoIt(True);
        Inc(p);
        s := p;
      end;
    #0 :
      begin
        DoIt(False);
        Break;
      end;
  else
    Inc(p);
  end;
end;

function PunycodeEncodeDomain(const str: UnicodeString): AnsiString;
var
  p, s: PWideChar;

  procedure DoIt(dot: Boolean);
  var
    inlen, outlen: Cardinal;
    ansi: AnsiString;
    a: PAnsiChar;
  begin
    inlen := p - s;
    if (PunycodeEncode(inlen, PPunyCode(s), outlen) = pcSuccess) and (inlen + 1 <> outlen) then
    begin
      if dot then
        SetLength(ansi, outlen + 4 + 1)
      else
        SetLength(ansi, outlen + 4);
      a := PAnsiChar(ansi);
      Move(PAnsiChar('xn--')^, a^, 4);
      inc(a, 4);
      PunycodeEncode(inlen, PPunyCode(s), outlen, PByte(a));
      if dot then
      begin
        inc(a, outlen);
        a^ := '.';
      end;
    end else
      if dot then
        SetString(ansi, s, inlen + 1)
      else
        SetString(ansi, s, inlen);
    Result := Result + ansi;
  end;

begin
  Result := '';
  p := PWideChar(str);
  s := p;

  while True do
  case p^ of
    '.':
      begin
        DoIt(True);
        Inc(p);
        s := p;
      end;
    #0 :
      begin
        DoIt(False);
        Break;
      end;
  else
    Inc(p);
  end;
end;

end.
```